# How do I create a dictionary structure from provided data recursively?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have list of tuples which is mentioned below where first element in tuple is key based on which I want to generate dictionary in specific format.

```py
# list variable
x = [  
(('Fresh Vegetables', 'Hamel', '2006', "Jimmy's Ebony Sweet Peas"), 209034.60000000001), 

(('Fresh Vegetables', 'Hamel', '2006', "Sue's Ebony Asparagus"), 217158.67000000001), 

(('Fresh Vegetables', 'Mentor', '2007', "Jimmy's Ebony Sweet Peas"), 225630.60000000001), 

(('Fresh Vegetables', 'Mentor', '2007',"Sue's Ebony Asparagus"), 233201.47), 

(('Fresh Vegetables', 'Hamel', '2006', "Bubba's Ebony Corn on the Cob"), 317588.95000000001), 

(('Fresh Vegetables','Mentor', '2007', "Bubba's Ebony Corn on the Cob"), 343151.59000000003), 

(('Fresh Vegetables', 'Sioux Center', '2007', "John's Ebony Squash"), 401308.01 000000001)
]
```

I want a structure of dictionary given below. where "**total**" key is total of every dictionary element's total in that dictionary.

```py
finalX = {
   'Fresh Vegetables':{

       'Hamel':{

           '2006':{

                 "Jimmy's Ebony Sweet Peas":209034.60000000001,
                 "Sue's Ebony Asparagus":217158.67000000001,
                 "Bubba's Ebony Corn on the Cob":317588.95000000001,
                 "total": 743782.22
            }
           "total":743782.22
       },   

       'Mentor':{

           '2007':{

               "Jimmy's Ebony Sweet Peas":225630.60000000001,
               "Sue's Ebony Asparagus":233201.47,
               "Bubba's Ebony Corn on the Cob":343151.59000000003,
               "total": 801983.66
           }
           "total":801983.66
       },

       'Sioux Center':{

           '2007':{

               "John's Ebony Squash":401308.01000000001
               "total":401308.01
           }
           "total":401308.01
       }
       "total":1947073.89
   }
}
```

I know that without recursion it's impossible but I am stuck there. How do I implement it? I tried some things but was not able to do it.

Comment: "i tried but was not able to do it." - Can you show what you have tried? You should always show your effort. That way you can be pointed to specific errors in your code/thinking and also your question is less likely to get downvoted/closed (as this is not a code writing service)

Comment: Its definitely possible with either recursion or iteration. Please try one of these methods and update your question with what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterative approach: first make it a dict, then add sub-totals:

```
import pprint

x = [
(('Fresh Vegetables', 'Hamel', '2006', "Jimmy's Ebony Sweet Peas"), 209034.60000000001),    
(('Fresh Vegetables', 'Hamel', '2006', "Sue's Ebony Asparagus"), 217158.67000000001),    
(('Fresh Vegetables', 'Mentor', '2007', "Jimmy's Ebony Sweet Peas"), 225630.60000000001),     
(('Fresh Vegetables', 'Mentor', '2007',"Sue's Ebony Asparagus"), 233201.47),    
(('Fresh Vegetables', 'Hamel', '2006', "Bubba's Ebony Corn on the Cob"), 317588.95000000001),     
(('Fresh Vegetables','Mentor', '2007', "Bubba's Ebony Corn on the Cob"), 343151.59000000003),     
(('Fresh Vegetables', 'Sioux Center', '2007', "John's Ebony Squash"), 401308.01000000001)]
```

**Create the dictionary:**

```
XX = {}
for n in x:
  what = n[0][0]
  wher = n[0][1]
  when = n[0][2]
  at   = n[0][3]
  amou = n[1]

  XX.setdefault(what,{}).setdefault(wher,{}).setdefault(when,{}).setdefault(at,0.0)    
  XX[what][wher][when][at] += amou
```

**Add all the sub-totals (see edit below for shorter version)**

```
# create the "total" sums in between:
for whatKey in XX:
  for wherKey in XX[whatKey]:
    for whenKey in  XX[whatKey][wherKey]:
      XX[whatKey][wherKey][whenKey]["total"] = 0.0
      for atKey in XX[whatKey][wherKey][whenKey]:
        if atKey != "total":
          XX[whatKey][wherKey][whenKey]["total"] += XX[whatKey][wherKey][whenKey][atKey]

for whatKey in XX:
  for wherKey in XX[whatKey]:
    for whenKey in  XX[whatKey][wherKey]:
      XX[whatKey][wherKey][whenKey]["total"] = 0.0
      for atKey in XX[whatKey][wherKey][whenKey]:
        if atKey != "total":
          XX[whatKey][wherKey][whenKey]["total"] += XX[whatKey][wherKey][whenKey][atKey]

for whatKey in XX:
  for wherKey in XX[whatKey]:
    XX[whatKey][wherKey]["total"] = 0
    for whenKey in  XX[whatKey][wherKey]:
      if whenKey != "total":
        XX[whatKey][wherKey]["total"] += XX[whatKey][wherKey][whenKey]["total"]

for whatKey in XX:
  XX[whatKey]["total"] = 0
  for wherKey in XX[whatKey]:
      if wherKey!= "total":
        XX[whatKey]["total"] += XX[whatKey][wherKey]["total"] 

pprint.pprint(XX)
```

Output (reformatted):

```
{'Fresh Vegetables': 
    {'Hamel': 
        {'2006': {"Bubba's Ebony Corn on the Cob": 317588.95,
                  "Jimmy's Ebony Sweet Peas": 209034.6,
                  "Sue's Ebony Asparagus": 217158.67,
                  'total': 743782.22},
         'total': 743782.22},

     'Mentor': 
         {'2007': {"Bubba's Ebony Corn on the Cob": 343151.59,
                   "Jimmy's Ebony Sweet Peas": 225630.6,
                   "Sue's Ebony Asparagus": 233201.47,
                   'total': 801983.66},
          'total': 801983.66},

     'Sioux Center': 
         {'2007': {"John's Ebony Squash": 401308.01,
                   'total': 401308.01},
          'total': 401308.01},

     'total': 1947073.89}}
```

---

**Edit** avoiding multiple complete `for` - iterations:

```
# create the "total" sums in between:
for whatKey in XX: 
  if whatKey == "total":
    continue
  XX[whatKey].setdefault("total",0)

  for wherKey in XX[whatKey]:
    if wherKey == "total":
      continue
    XX[whatKey][wherKey].setdefault("total",0)

    for whenKey in  XX[whatKey][wherKey]: 
      if whenKey == "total":
        continue      
      XX[whatKey][wherKey][whenKey].setdefault("total",0)

      for atKey in XX[whatKey][wherKey][whenKey]:
        if atKey == "total":
          continue

        XX[whatKey][wherKey][whenKey]["total"] += XX[whatKey][wherKey][whenKey][atKey]
        XX[whatKey][wherKey]["total"] += XX[whatKey][wherKey][whenKey][atKey]
        XX[whatKey]["total"] += XX[whatKey][wherKey][whenKey][atKey]
```

Comment: thanks sir it worked. but multiple for loops? is there any recursive way possible? because that tuple's first elements may vary.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float))))

for k, v in x:
    d[k[0]][k[1]][k[2]][k[3]] = v

for k1 in d:
    d[k1]['total'] = sum(d[k1][j][k][l] for j in d[k1] for k in d[k1][j] for l in d[k1][j][k])
    for k2 in set(d[k1])-{'total'}:
        d[k1][k2]['total'] = sum(d[k1][k2][k][l] for k in d[k1][k2] for l in d[k1][k2][k])
        for k3 in set(d[k1][k2])-{'total'}:
            d[k1][k2][k3]['total'] = sum(d[k1][k2][k3][l] for l in d[k1][k2][k3])
```

Comment: I envy ppl with python skills that compresses stuff like this in 8-10 lines. Have to have a look at defaultdict, only know Counter from collections so far. +1

Answer (score 2):

A bit more human readable solution.

Here is just the main dictionary part. The point I want to illustrate is that, even with simple recursion, some generic solution can be achieved.

However, for the sub-total, it requires some additional operation which is not covered yet in this solution.

```
from functools import reduce
import collections

# function to convert a list/tuple to dictionary tree
def totree(keys, value):
  if len(keys) == 1:
    return {keys[0]: value}
  else:
    return {keys[0]: totree(keys[1:], value)}

# function to update nested dictionary
def update(d, u):
    for k, v in u.items():
        if isinstance(v, collections.Mapping):
            d[k] = update(d.get(k, {}), v)
        else:
            d[k] = v
    return d

# the expected dictionary is saved to d
d = reduce(lambda d1, d2: update(d1, d2), map(lambda sub:totree(*sub), x)))

print(d)
```

Comment: the point was not the "parsing" but adding all the calculated sub-totals. yours does as much as as what I titled **Create the dictionary** in my answer ... the trickyer part is calculating all the sub-totals. Although i now have to look up reduce as well, so thanks for that.

Comment: @PatrickArtner You are right. That involves additional operation. However, with just simple recursion, I am afraid this is already farthest I can achieve. I am still thinking about it. I will update my answer while I get some idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
local_dict = {}
for veg in x:
    item,center, year, dish = veg[0]
    amount  = veg[1]
    if item in local_dict:
        data = local_dict[item]
        if center in data:
            data_center = data[center]
            data_center['total'] += amount
            if year in data_center:
                get_dict = data_center[year]
                if dish in get_dict or (dish not in get_dict):
                    get_dict[dish] = amount
                get_dict["total"] += amount
            else:
                data_center[year] = {dish:amount,"total":amount}
                data_center["total"] = amount
        else:
            data[center] = {year:{dish:amount,"total":amount},"total":amount}
    else:
        local_dict.setdefault(item,{center:{year:{dish:amount,"total":amount},"total":amount}})
print(local_dict)
```